# File Upload Remove Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a File Upload Control on my ASP.NET MVC project and I want to remove the text next to it where it says: "No file chosen".

The link to the File Upload is: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I have checked the javascript file and the css file and I can't seem to find where it injects the "No file chosen" sentence.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT**

This is an image of what it currently looks like. Even though I want to get rid of the "No file chosen" text.

[image]

Comment: You can't. File inputs, like selects, are OS controls. You can only make minor modifications with CSS and even then, it's so limited that you're better off not even bothering.

Comment: Wow... that's... hmmm... Looks like i'll have to work around it.

Comment: Why is it though that when I inspect the element in Chrome then all I see is:

<input type="file" id="fileupload" name="image">

It doesn't show the button, button's text or the "No file chosen" text next to it.

Comment: Take a look at my edit if it helps.

Comment: Because it's an OS control, or I guess more appropriately a browser control. The `<input type="file">` simply instructs the browser to insert a file upload control into the page at that location. The OS / browser determines what the control will be. OS X generally used the the "Choose a file"/"No file chosen" format, while Windows used the traditional text-input style. Now, the lines have blurred a bit as Chrome and Safari for Windows carry over the "Mac style" to Windows and Firefox uses the "Windows style" on Mac.